# Array en GSON recorrer

Tags: android, json, gson

Estoy dandole vueltas, pero no consigo imprimir por consola el nombre y la edad del json Crospromotion. Estoy utilizando la libreria GSON, pero estoy ahora mismo atascado y no se como avanzar.

**Tengo mi JSON**

```
    {
        "crospromotion": [
            {
              "name": "Orus",
              "age":14
            },
            {
              "name": "Michelle",
              "age":29
            },
            {
              "name": "Jack",
              "age":29
            }
          ],
          "totalAccessorios": 20,
          "totalCaras": 20
    }
```

**Mi clase controlador JSon:**

```
public class Data {    
  private Crospromotion crospromotion;    
  private int totalAccessorios, totalCaras;
        
    public int getTotalAccessorios() {
         return totalAccessorios;
    }
        
    public int getTotalCaras() {
         return totalCaras;
    }
        
}
```

**Clase Crospromotion:**

```
public class Crospromotion {
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
final Data data = gson.fromJson(myResponse, Data.class);
Log.d("MEN: ", data.getTotalAccessorios());
// Quiero imprimir en Log, los campos Crospromotion: name y age. Pero no se como seguir.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que pasa es que los nombres de las variables que están intentando parsear con gson son incorrectos. Deben tener el mismo nombre que que el json.

```
        {
          "name": "Orus",
          "age":14
        }
```

Los nombres son **name** y **age**

```
public class Crospromotion {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Ahora si lo que quieres hacer es conservar el nombre de las variables, puedes utilizar `@SerializedName`.

```
    public class Crospromotion {
        @SerializedName("name")
        private String nombre;

        @SerializedName("age")
        private int edad;

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public int getEdad() {
            return edad;
        }
    }
```

Update :

El json que te retorna es una lista. entonces deberias esperar una lista y no un objeto. Para hacer esto podrías intentar lo siguientes:

```
public class Data {    
    private List<Crospromotion> crospromotion = new ArrayList<>();    
    private int totalAccessorios, totalCaras;
    
    public int getTotalAccessorios() {
        return totalAccessorios;
    }
    
    public int getTotalCaras() {
       return totalCaras;
   }
    
}
```

Reemplazar recibir un objeto por recibir una lista `private List<Crospromotion> crospromotion = new ArrayList<>();`

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: No puedo mostrar en pantalla el LOG. 
Me da el siguiente fallo:  (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference)

Comment: Tienes razón, acabo de actualizar la respuesta :)